# asp.net web application - alert/message box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I have an asp.net web application. 
On clicking a button, on the server side some code is executed. If the code is successfully executed I want an alert popup box to be shown to the user informing them of the successful completion of the action.

Any ideas?

Kind Regards,
Fiona

Comment: alerts are a bad way to show messages to users.

Comment: Yes, users could feel worried by an alert. Use an advice, instead. Users will feel more comfortable. ;) BTW, epascarello is right: there are tons of more appealing methods to send info to the users.

Comment: Sorry for delay in responding.. I followed your advice and am no longer displaying an alert! User will now receive a successful message on the page.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Google "alert asp.net" will give you plenty of solutions using the javascript alert function.

Even better, googling "jquery alert asp.net" will give you jquery solutions (an html modal popup which is modal to the current page, but allows you to switch to other tabs in a tabbed browser).

Comment: @user1394965 because there's boatloads of crap on the web if you search for anything. Outdated code, untested code, code that just doesn't work and hasnt'since it was posted, and then there's the copycats that post such code samples all over Q&A sites. Though that doesn't aid OP here, because s/he should've shown what has been tried.

Comment: Thanks for responding.. yes I had googled and attempted a number of the solutions offered.. none worked which is why i posted here. I had tried so many ways I thought that by posting what I'd tried would make the question more complicated.. I will look into solutions suggested here. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

server side code and clide side code run in different contexts, 
I think your best approach would be to post with ajax or jquery like:

```
$.post(url,parameters, function(){
    //this code runs after the post
    alert('my message')
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you a couple of solutions.

1. Create a Javascript `onclick` event handler that executes an AJAX call to your business code. The `success` callback of the call will display the alert. References [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). I prefer this solution.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'path/to/my/business/handler.ashx',
       data: ({/*my json data*/}),
       error: function (request, status, error) {
           alert("Something wrong here!");
           return false;
       },
       success: function (returnData) {
           alert("Everything fine here!");
       }
   });
   ```
2. Manage the `onclick` event with a server side event handler. When the business logic has been executed, you can register a javascript script that execute the alert. References [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx).

   ```
   ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
   Type csType = this.GetType();
   cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, "handler", @"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Eveything fine here!');</script>");
   ```

Comment: Hi ADC, Im working on an application that has grown into a monster and unfortunately I've to work with the existing code.. as a result I can't go down the AJAX route.. so what I've tried is option 2. The onclick event for the button executes and as a last step I've registered the javascript that executes the alert. However the alert is never shown. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you checked the javascript console? The page source in the browser features the registered block?